# Flash + iOS + additional files

Tags: iphone, flash, ios, pixel-bender

So flash allows to create iOS apps. The compiler creates an .ipa file which I can load on the iPhone.

But what about additional files?

I'd like to use a pixel bender file (.pbj) which i have to load with URLLoader. But how do I get the pbj file into the .ipa file?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the the iPhone OS Settings and under the General tab there is a place to include files. Click on the + or on the +folder icon to include a file or folder.

Answer (score 0):

Pixel Bender files don't run under iOS. See other limitations here:
http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Applications_for_iPhone:Developer_FAQ#Which_Flash_Platform_tools_and_technologies_can_be_used_to_build_content_for_iOS.3F